# Attributes for main function parameters

Tags: c++, function, parameters, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

Can I use attributes for main function parameters or is it implementation defined?

[Looks like](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) main function has only 2 supported forms without [*attribute-list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr#nt:attribute-list) while the general [function declaration syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) does have it.

Example:

```
int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, char* argv[]);
```

Comment: [Main function - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) and [C++ Standard - 6.3.1 (latest draft)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yeah, i did mention this link in my question

Comment: Added the C++ standard draft. You don't want to play with the parameters of `main()` that is your program entry point and the function is governed by the standard. You are likely to break a lot more than you fix toying with it. Yes, anything other than `(int, char *[])` will be implementation defined. In a *freestanding environment* (no OS), the entire program-startup function will be implementation defined and need not even be named `main()`.

Comment: Attributes aren't part of argument/function type, so there should be no difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed there is no explicit requirement that attributes must be accepted for main function parameters [basic.start.main](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.main#:argc).

But on the other hand if you read [dcl.attr.unused#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.attr.unused#5) you can't find anything special for main which says that is not allowed there.

This attribute must be known by a compiler to be C++17 conformant, but even unknown attributes should not cause errors. You can find this in the standard:

> Any attribute-token that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored. [dcl.attr#grammar-6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.attr#grammar-6)

Unfortunately attributes can cause sometimes errors (even if they shouldn't). See for expamle this issue: [GSL_SUPPRESS](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/1173).

In practice your code is accepted by all major compilers without a warning [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/QQJUnf). Therefore I would say it is okay.
But because it is allowed to have a main function which takes no arguments I would prefer that.

Comment: In addition:
For function parameters you can omit their name - this is the "old way" to signal that you need this argument only for overload resolution.

You could write int main(int, char*[])
{
  return 0;
}

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use attributes for main function parameters or is it implementation defined?

From [dcl.attr.grammar](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.grammar#6):

> For an attribute-token (including an attribute-scoped-token) not specified in this document, the behavior is implementation-defined.

Since the attribute appertains to the parameter, and that affects the declaration of `main`, the behavior of such a program is implementation-defined, and is not portable across conforming implementations.

For your example of `[[maybe_unused]]`, this attribute is specified in [dcl.attr.unused](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.unused). There appears to be no wording that this attribute affects the type of a variable declaration, or has any other semantic effect on the behavior of the program, so this program is portable.

Comment: I doubt that attributes affect the type whatsoever though? The [[maybe_unused]] specifier in particular applies to the use of a particular variable, not to its type. In all cases I've seen attributes are more hints to the compiler about how to carry out translation, not affecting the language rules or semantics at all.

Comment: Additionally, like how the other answer said, attributes that are not supported by a given compiler are required by the standard to be ignored by that compiler. If [[maybe_unused]] doesn't make sense to the compiler in this instance, the compiler should translate the rest unchanged.

Comment: Attributes do not affect function signature. They are rather just hints to compiler.

Comment: I didn't quite get it. "Since the attribute pertains to the parameter ... the behavior ... is not portable" but "... so this program is portable". Does it mean that `[[maybe_unused]]` is okay and others not?

Comment: @helloworld Yes, `[[maybe_unused]]` behavior is specified, and it's fine, but in general, an attribute might change the behavior of a program.